# C++ FileIO weird behaviour

Tags: c++, file-io, windows-8.1, ofstream

While writing a program I came accross a strange behaviour of `std::ofstream`. Please refer to the code below

```
ofstream dire;
dire.open("dir.txt", std::ios::out);

// some other code

for(int i=0;i<dir.size();i++)
{
    dire << dir[i] << "\t"; // dir is integer vector containing values between 0-9
}
```

Now when I open `dir.txt` contents are:

```
ऴऴऴऴवववववववववशशशशशशशशशशषषषषषषषषरररररररऱऱऱऱऱऱऱऱऱललललललललललललळ.. and so on
```

if I give a space and then tab(\t) then it works correctly or for that matter \n also works correctly. `dire << dir[i] << " \t";`

And now the output is:

```
4   4   4   4   5   5   5   5   5   5.. and so on
```

I also tried `dire.flush()` to flush the output buffer to file, but still the same result.

I can definitely get away by using `\t` but I would like to learn why this is happening.

Comment: Open `dir.txt` with a hex editor. What do you see?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Notepad to look at the file then the bug [Bush hid the facts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts) can be the problem.

> The bug occurs when the string is passed to the Win32 charset detection function IsTextUnicode with no other characters. IsTextUnicode sees what it thinks is valid UTF-16LE Chinese and returns true, and the application then incorrectly interprets the text as UTF-16LE.

Comment: This is exactly what's going on, `ऴ` is 0x3409 in UTF-16LE, which just happens to be the same as `4\t` in single byte encoding.